# Can any one explain what is call by value in java?

Tags: java

```
package com.test;

public class Callbyvalref {
    int data = 50;
    int x = 10;

    void change(Callbyvalref call) {
        call.data = call.data + 500;
    }

    void nochange(int x) {
        x = x + 25;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Callbyvalref call = new Callbyvalref();
        call.change(call);
        System.out.println("Call By reference: " + call.data);
        call.nochange(500);
        System.out.println("Call By Value: " + call.x);
    }

}
```

Call By reference: 550
Call By Value: 10

When I change

```
void nochange(int y) {
    x = x + 25;
}
```

Call By reference: 550
Call By Value: 35

Both times Call.x printing different values.. any one can explain what is the changes happening when argument variable is changed..

Comment: I don't see what you don't understand. And this example is, again, misleading. Java is pass by value and NOT pass by reference...

Comment: java is always pass by value. http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/24/pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In above code, in the method

```
void nochange(int x) {
        x = x + 25;
    }
```

the **local variable** in that function is being **changed**. If you change the above method as below:

```
void nochange(int x) {
        this.x = x + 25;
    }
```

OR

```
void nochange(int y) {
        x = y + 25;
    }
```

You can see what is happening there.

Comment: Fine got it.. the variable x in nochange method is local.. i thought it is referring instance variable.. Thanks for the clarification..

Answer (score 0):

This is basicly happening because Java does provide the information for an object as reference which is passed by value.

i´ll just leave you this article for further investigations.

[Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a primitive to a method, only the value is copied. The argument is a new local variable that is initialized with the value passed to it, and has no relation to the "original" value. If you modify it, you're just modifying a local variable, and cannot effect the variable used in the method call.